# Why are both if-Statements seperatly working, but together they don't?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, if-statement

I guess this is a really easy problem, but I just started Programming. I tried to Set the Player as a Child of a Platform while they touch, so he is moving with it. And if there is only one such Platform in the Game it works, but otherwise, the Player can only stick on the Platform I placed last. On the otherones, both bools isOnBlock and findPlayer are set true (I tested this), but the first If-Statement still doesn`t work.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class HaftungAnBlock : MonoBehaviour
{

public bool isOnBlock;
private GameObject myPlayer;
bool findPlayer;


public void FindPlayer()
{
    myPlayer = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
    findPlayer = true;
}
void Update()
{
    if (isOnBlock && findPlayer)
    {
            myPlayer.transform.SetParent(this.transform);
    } 
    else if (!isOnBlock && findPlayer)
    {
        myPlayer.transform.SetParent(null);
    }
}

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        isOnBlock = true;
    }
}
private void OnCollisionExit(Collision other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        isOnBlock = false;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Which if statement doesn't work? You have 3 and an else if.

Comment: In general: How exactly can the collision exit if you are a child of that platform?! In general **never** nest Rigidbody under other objects! If you wan to make it follow another Rigidbody (like your platform) then rather use [Joints](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Joints.html)!

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you have multiple platforms, at least one will always set the parent transform to null(since you can at most have one platform below the player, i assume), meaning that even if you stand on a platform it's a race condition for which platform updates first in the loop, as platform #2 and platform #3 will try to set the parent to null.

A fix to this would be anchoring the player to the platform within the trigger methods, rather than within the update method, so that each platform only cares about what happens when the player enters/exits that specific platform, and not what happens in the rest of the game world.

I don't know your exact setup though, so my approach might not be the correct way to handle it for your scenario, but just throwing it out there.

Comment: Ok, did you mean like this:     `private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
    {
                if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player") && findPlayer)
        {
            myPlayer.transform.SetParent(this.transform);
        }
    }
                    private void OnCollisionExit(Collision other)
    {
                                    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player") && findPlayer)
        {
            myPlayer.transform.SetParent(null);
        }
    }`

Comment: Something along those lines yeah, again, i don't know the specifics of your project, if platforms are meant to overlap, then it's still gonna be troublesome, but from an outside perspective your code should work as intended with those changes.
Another guy also mentioned using joints instead of nesting, which seems like a better solution than my fix, i'm not a unity guru after all